# Inline Hyperlink navigate to Page

Tags: c#, xaml, hyperlink, uwp, inline

I'm constructing text, and some pieces of the text should contain a hyperlink. However, these hyperlinks do not redirect to a webpage but should open a page in the UWP app (the currently running UWP app, not a new instance of it or a different app).

A `HyperlinkButton` can only open URL's that lead to an external browser, it can't open a page inside the app.

Using an `InlineUIContainer` doesn't work, I get

> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
>   Additional information: Value does not fall within the expected range.

With this code

```
List<Inline> ic = new List<Inline>();
InlineUIContainer container = new InlineUIContainer();
TextBlock tbClickable = new TextBlock();
tbClickable.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
tbClickable.Text = label?.name;
tbClickable.Tag = label?.id;
tbClickable.Tapped += TbArtist_Tapped;
container.Child = tbClickable;
ic.Add(container);
```

When I use

```
foreach (var item in ic)
{
    dTb.Inlines.Add(item);
}
```

Where `tbCurrent` is the `TextBlock`.

Any other ways to get a clickable link as an Inline element?
Best case scenario I can attach a `Tapped`/`Click` event handler.
But opening the page via a URI method or so is also good.

Comment: The documentation for `HyperlinkButton` tells you [how to do this](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.HyperlinkButton)

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT The problem is a TextBlock does not accept an InlineUIContainer, so I can't add a HyperlinkButton as this needs to be inside an InlineUIContainer. A HyperlinkButton is not an inline element by itself.

Comment: Try `Hyperlink` instead. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.documents.hyperlink

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT That doesn't work, as it only accepts URI's that will open outside the app. As described in the docs: "When a user clicks or taps the Hyperlink element, the specified Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) opens in the default browser. The default browser runs in a separate process from your app.".
However, I managed to get it to work in a RichTextBlock with a HyperlinkButton. I will post the answer once I cleaned up my code.

Comment: Did you read the next paragraph? "Use the Click event for actions other than launching a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) in a browser, such as navigation within the app."

Comment: Ah damn, didn't see that. I solved it in another way, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed to a RichTextBlock and using Blocks I could add a clickable TextBlock.
This works in UWP.

```
List<Block> ic = new List<Block>();
Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
InlineUIContainer iuic = new InlineUIContainer();
TextBlock hpb = new TextBlock();
hpb.Text = "link text";
hpb.Tag = "some tag to pass on to the click handler";
hpb.Tapped += ClickHandler;
hpb.TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline;
hpb.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush((Windows.UI.Color)page.Resources["SystemAccentColor"]);
iuic.Child = hpb;

para.Inlines.Add(iuic);
ic.Add(para);
```

Comment: Hey @CoCaIceDew, that is my intention, but StackOverflow is making me wait another hour before being able to do so :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason you could not use a `HyperlinkButton` for this. Quick example:

```
<HyperlinkButton Click="HyperlinkButton_Click" Content="Click me" />
```

And the `Click` handler:

```
private void HyperlinkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
}
```

Comment: The problem is a TextBlock does not accept an InlineUIContainer, so I can't add a HyperlinkButton as this needs to be inside an InlineUIContainer. A HyperlinkButton is not an inline element by itself.